# Table start from the second page (and truncated at the bottom)

Tags: latex

I'm a newcomer and now have a program generated latex code like following which used to compile to a PDF table. However, the compiled table start from the second page, leaving the first page blank, and there's some overlapping of text at the bottom of the table. Any suggestion on fixing these two problems?

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%-------------------------------------
\begin{document}    
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx} {11cm} {@{} l Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y@{}} \\
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Local Hukou}} \\
\cmidrule(l{.75em}){2-4} 
&\textbf{yes}&\textbf{No}&\textbf{Total} \\
\midrule
\textbf{Education}&&& \\
Not College graduates&1,530&759&2,289\\
College graduates&858&316&1,174\\
\textbf{Total}&2,388&1,075&3,463\\
& & &  \\
Not College graduates&66.8\%&33.2\%&100.0\% \\
College graduates&73.1\%&26.9\%&100.0\% \\
\textbf{Total}&69.0\%&31.0\%&100.0\% \\
& & &  \\
Not College graduates&64.10\%&70.60\%&66.10\% \\
College graduates&35.90\%&29.40\%&33.90\% \\
\textbf{Total}&100.0\%&100.0\%&100.0\% \\
\midrule
\textbf{Marriage}&&& \\
No&299&70&369 \\
Yes&1,975&964&2,939\\
\textbf{Total}&2,274&1,034&3,308\\
& & &  \\
No&81.0\%&19.0\%&100.0\% \\
Yes&67.2\%&32.8\%&100.0\% \\
\textbf{Total}&68.7\%&31.3\%&100.0\% \\
& & &  \\
No&13.1\%&6.8\%&11.2\% \\
Yes&86.9\%&93.2\%&88.8\% \\
\textbf{Total}&100.0\%&100.0\%&100.0\% \\

\midrule
\textbf{Employ Status}&&& \\
have a job&2,040&935&2,975\\
No job&348&140&488\\
\textbf{Total}&2,388&1,075&3,463\\
& & &  \\
have a job&68.6\%&31.4\%&100.0\% \\
No job&71.3\%&28.7\%&100.0\% \\
\textbf{Total}&69.0\%&31.0\%&100.0\% \\
& & &  \\
have a job&85.4\%&87.0\%&85.9\% \\
No job&14.6\%&13.0\%&14.1\% \\
\textbf{Total}&100.0\%&100.0\%&100.0\% \\
\midrule
\textbf{Works character}&&& \\
Not be employed&746&332&1,078 \\
Be employed&1,642&743&2,385\\
\textbf{Total}&2,388&1,075&3,463\\
& & &  \\
Not be employed&69.2\%&30.8\%&100.0\% \\
Be employed&68.8\%&31.2\%&100.0\% \\
\textbf{Total}&69.0\%&31.0\%&100.0\% \\
& & &  \\
Not be employed&31.2\%&30.9\%&31.1\% \\
Be employed&68.8\%&69.1\%&68.9\% \\
\textbf{Total}&100.0\%&100.0\%&100.0\% \\
\midrule
\textbf{Employer's character}&&& \\
other job&1,991&950&2,941\\
state sectors job&397&125&522\\
\textbf{Total}&2,388&1,075&3,463 \\
& & &  \\
other job&67.7\%&32.3\%&100.0\% \\
state sectors job&76.1\%&23.9\%&100.0\% \\
 \textbf{Total}&69.0\%&31.0\%&100.0\% \\
& & &  \\
other job&83.4\%&88.4\%&84.9\% \\
state sectors job&16.6\%&11.6\%&15.1% \\
\textbf{Total}&100.0\%&100.0\%&100.0\% \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[.75ex]
\end{tabularx}
\par
\scriptsize{\emph{Source: }CHFS}
\normalsize
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was looking around on this one, there was an answer about `tabularx` tables that spanned multiple pages and it was `\usepackage{ltablex}`. Then your `tabularx` can have a pagebreak between tabular lines.

If you add this line in your preamble you will find that your document is now 2 pages and the table starts on page 1 and goes onto page 2.

The problem with the last line is you missed a `\`:

```
state sectors job&16.6\%&11.6\%&15.1% \\
```

should be

```
state sectors job&16.6\%&11.6\%&15.1\% \\
```